# if a script is triggerd by a udev-rule, why does systemctl commands inside need to be invoked with sudo?

Tags: shell-script, udev, systemctl

First: The default User the system is working with, is root.
this is <s>needed by other processes and functionality</s> currently not better implemented.
OS: Fedora 35

I have a udev rule which fires a script if a hdmi device gets plugged in:

```
ACTION=="change", SUBSYSTEM=="drm", ENV{DISPLAY}=":0",ENV{XAUTHORITY}="/root/.Xauthority", RUN+="/bin/bash hdmi_hotplug_detection.sh"
```

Inside the script i have some logic to change the resolution and so on.
ALSO i want to restart a service which is running in the *--user* context.

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --auto
/usr/bin/systemctl --user restart daemon.service
```

which fails if udev is firing the script.
But if i invoke the *systemctl* command via `sudo` its working as expected.

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --auto
sudo /usr/bin/systemctl --user restart daemon.service
```

`xrandr` is working without sudo.

---

I added a `echo $(whoami)` to my script which states its running as root (even if triggerd from udev)
so would asume i dont need sudo?!

==========

my main problem with this behavior is, that i also trigger this script manually or via a pyhton script - which is failing than cause of the `sudo` with:

```
Failed to connect to bus: $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS and $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not defined (consider using --machine=<user>@.host --user to connect to bus of other user)
```

Whats the reason for this Behavior?
Why do i need the `sudo`?

---

My Workaround is:

```
if [[ $1 = "-no-sudo" ]]; then
    systemctl='/usr/bin/systemctl'
else
    systemctl='sudo /usr/bin/systemctl'
fi

$systemctl --user restart daemon.service
```

so udev is starting it with sudo and i have the possibility to start it without.